# Alternating colors not showing in web browser

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to create a table with alternating colors using javascript.  However, I ran into some trouble.

I would like to have the header black, and the rows alternate blue and gray.  However, whenever I run the page in a web browser, the header is black and the rows remain white.  The code does work on JSFiddle though displaying the rows with alternating colors.

Here's the code I used for the alternate row colors and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKnGe/3/)

```
var tblrows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tblrows.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0) tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
    else tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#C0C0C0';
}
```

Comment: Why not use just CSS?

Comment: FYI, it's fairly easy to use CSS to accomplish this these days. Also, note that IE historically needed the background applied to the TD, rather than the TR

Comment: Also, your JSFiddle works just fine in Chrome, so I'm guessing you're looking at it in IE. Easiest fix? Stop using IE. :)

Comment: Yes, we need clarification here. Are you saying your code works as you intended on JSFiddle but doesn't elsewhere? If so, then the problem is elsewhere. We need to know more about that other environment to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your js code after the DOM has been populated.
Place your JavaScript code after the < table> you are targeting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>

    <table> <tr> Your table content goes here </tr> </table>

    <script>
        var tblrows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(i=0;i<tblrows.length;i++){
            if(i%2==0) tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
            else tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#C0C0C0';} </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If your JavaScript is in a separate file, by including it just before the closing body tag you can ensure it will run after the DOM has been populated.

```
...
  <script src="theJavascriptFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, it must be executed after all the associated table rows have been inserted into the DOM.

To accomplish this, you can wrap the code in a separate function executed afterwards (which is exactly what JS Fiddle's separate script box does), or else you can place the code in a `script` tag which is placed after all of your document's HTML content. (This second method may not work if your table rows are generated dynamically.)

CSS also has odd and even rules if you want to use them, designed for exactly your situation. Here is the canonical reference example on the subject from eleven years ago (and updated since then): http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html